# Xcode 6.1 and Tesflight on iOS 8.1.1: Cannot attach to process

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am trying to debug an annoying issue where my app downloaded through Testflight randomly crashes (it doesn't when executed on my iDevice using Xcode), but I cannot attach the debugger to the running process. It says "Lost connection  to device" every time I try to attach it. I can, however, attach it to the app if I execute the app directly from Xcode.

Any ideas area appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the crash report that iOS generates and analyse that one.

Comment: Oddly, there are no crash reports for testflight applications either!

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue... I have an issue where my app is functioning differently when downloaded through iTunes Connect TestFlight than when running it straight from Xcode... When run form Xcode, it works perfectly, but when run from the TestFlight install, it has some error. When trying to attach the debugger to the TestFlight installed version, Xcode just says "Lost connection to device" it's quite annoying...